# How to 'append' the background with more styles in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I need a way to 'append' the style to the same div in css. I know this can be done with jQuery, but I wonder if it'll be possible just using the stylesheet.

My div has a class .myClass, and then later I give it a custom attribute "customAttr". I need background image to be put on top of gradient.

In the example below, I actually specify attribute and class at the same time. In the real thing though, I need to be able to add it at a later point, such that image will appear on top of the previously visible background. Also, I would have many more backgrounds specified to accommodate for older browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/mgboss/eyw4v82f/3/

```
div {
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
}

div[customAttr="hello"] {
    background-image: url("http://s22.postimg.org/5cvkclhi5/bolt.png");
}

div.myClass {
    background: background: linear-gradient(red, blue);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You say that later you add a custom attribute how are you adding that attribute?

Comment: I'm doing it with jQuery. Of course I could do same with image, but it's more messy. Plus I'm just wondering if it's possible with css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS gradients are also values of `background-image` (even if specified with `background` shorthand), so even with correct specificity of selectors you will have to specify both picture and gradient as multiple background:

```css
div {
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
}

.myClass[customAttr="hello"] {
    background: url("http://s22.postimg.org/5cvkclhi5/bolt.png"), linear-gradient(red, blue);
}

.myClass {
    background: linear-gradient(red, blue);
}
```

```html
<div class="myClass" customAttr="hello"></div>
```

Alternatively, you can add extra images with pseudo elements:

```css
div {
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    position: relative;
}

.myClass[customAttr="hello"]::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url("http://s22.postimg.org/5cvkclhi5/bolt.png");
}

.myClass {
    background: linear-gradient(red, blue);
}
```

```html
<div class="myClass" customAttr="hello"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I knew this was possible, though I was looking for a nicer solution. I'll be sticking with this one I guess. I'm using Less to compile my css file, because I have multiple attributes and classes and I need to apply backgrounds to their various combinations, lots of typing otherwise!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way too..

```
div.myClass {
    background:    url("http://s22.postimg.org/5cvkclhi5/bolt.png") no-repeat,
     linear-gradient(red, blue) ;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/umairorana/6mc2v7mx/

Answer (score 0):

Is this the kind of effect you're looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/ben220/e3912d78/

HTML:

```
<body>
<div></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    height: 350px;
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
    background: linear-gradient(red, blue);
}

div::after {
    content:"";
    background: url("tree.jpg") no-repeat;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

The only way I could think of to do this was to add opacity to the background image but there seems to be no conventional way to do this in CSS. You can however use the ::after property was a work-around. This basically allows you to insert content into your webpage without changing the HTML. In this example I've only included one div in the HTML code. The other, which contains the background image, is purely done with css.

I hope this helps.

Ben